# How to add 1920x1200 Resolution to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro which has an aspect ratio of 2560 x 1600 (16:10) and my fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 only provides one resolution. The icons are too small, fonts are too small, everything is too small.

Is there a way I could add this 1920x1200 resolution to Ubuntu 20? I already saw some instructions like this but I am confused about the numbers whether what to put there.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118
```

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new resolution, you could scale it to 150% by enabling fractional scaling.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qpv1if/how_to_add_1920x1200_resolution_to_ubuntu_2004/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).